# How to compile CIL code (intermediate code used on .NET) using ilasm for Linux and OSX?

Tags: .net, linux, macos, cil, ilasm

I used the `runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm` nuget to get ilasm.exe to compile my CIL codes. It compiles everything correctly for the windows .exe PE, but apparently it doesn't compile for Linux and MacOS...

I know that using .NET 5.0 or newer with the `dotnet --runtime` command is able to compile for any supported OS. How to do this using CIL instead of C#? I thought it was using `ilasm.exe`, but apparently it's not possible, so what would be the solution for that?

Note: I already used the linux `ilasm` and the code compiled on linux was a .exe PE, an extension and format that doesn't work on linux (linux uses ELF format)

Comment: You shouldn't reference this package explicitly, instead use [`Microsoft.Net.SDK.IL`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11411)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compile MSIL I use following template:

```
ProjectName
|- ProjectName.ilproj
|- Program.il
```

`ProjectName.ilproj` content:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Net.Sdk.il/7.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

`Program.il` content:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.assembly 'App' {}

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit abstract sealed Program extends [mscorlib]System.Object {
    .method private hidebysig static void Main ( string[] args) cil managed {
        .entrypoint

        ldstr "hw"
        call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)

        ret
    }
}
```

This setup allows me to compile programs without any problems. Commands `dotnet build -r linux-x64 --self-contained -c release` and `dotnet build -r win-x64 --self-contained -c release` seems to work and produce some platform-specific output

Comment: This solution is perfect for my problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing experiments, you can run `.exe` with Mono runtime, `mono your.exe`.

While .NET CLI should also accept it `dotnet your.exe`, you need to add supporting files, such as `.dep.json`, to specify information such as runtime.

BTW, like the comment indicated, use native IL support in .NET Core SDK is a better approach.